# ICEfaces 3.3.0 based application not responding any user event

Tags: weblogic11g, icefaces-3

We are currently migrating an ICEfaces based application from version 1.8.2 to 3.3.0. We've followed instructions and tutorials from ICEsoft documentation and finally managed to have partially-functional migrated version working on our local environment, where we use Tomcat 6.0 as an application server. On tomcat, we can access de application, login, and navigate some pages.

However, after deploying the migrated application to Weblogic 11g application server (version 10.3.2), the login page shows, but it doesn't respond to any user event. For example, when clicking on the Enter button nothing occurs. The same occurs when clicking on the sign-up button, or the links that change te active language. On Tomcat that is working fine, the request is processed and the navigation occurs to the next page.

We've checked with firebug that no request is being send when clicking on any button or link. So, it seems to be a javascript issue. If we review the browser console, we only see a message like that (from bridge.js):

```
   "[window] full submit to http://XXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY/login.jsf
   javax.faces.execute: @all
   javax.faces.render: @all
   javax.faces.source: formulario:entrar
   view ID: vka1qb5a
   event type: click"
```

No errors, no warnings.

As I said, user events are processed correctly when the application is running on Tomcat, but nothing occurs when the application is running on Weblogic.

Any idea why this issue may be happening?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.